# bash: Regex: Find and replace a variable in a file

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have a bash script which should find a regex match in a file, and replace it's content.

So what I have in the file it's this (it's a version string in a package.json):

```
// ...
"version": "1.2.13",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
// ...
```

Now I want to match the number (the 13), increase it and replace it with the current one.
What I have so far is a solution with `awk`, which doesn't work.

```
awk -v lvar="$VAR" '/version":\s"[0-9]+.[0-9]+.([0-9]+)/{print $0}' ${PACKAGE_JSON_PATH}

echo ${lvar}
```

The pattern works so, it gives me the last number. However, the awk statement doesn't work.

The output looks like this:

```
"version": "1.2.13",
```

So what it does: It prints the entire line. But, I just want the 13 out of that. And, it doesn't save it into the `lvar` variable.

Sorry, I'm quite new to this bash stuff :)

Comment: Relevant : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361427/backreference-in-awk-regex

Comment: sed -r is what you want when fiddling with regexp. `sed -r '/version":/ s/version":\s"[0-9]+.[0-9]+.([0-9]+)/\1/' ${PACKAGE_JSON_PATH}` will give you the expected result

Comment: `lvar` is AWK's variable; it's not exported to Bash so `echo ${lvar}` has little effect.

Comment: Sorry `sed -nr '/version":/ s/"version":\s"[0-9]+.[0-9]+.([0-9]+)".*/\1/p' ${PACKAGE_JSON_PATH}` is the right command since the -n option keep the other line to be printed.

Comment: @hiolaf The OP is trying to replace a number with the value of that number plus 1. sed can't do arithmetic operations like addition so this isn't a job for sed.

Comment: your description is contradicting: you said *increase it*, then *I just want the 13 out of that*. Elaborate your requirements, what value should `lvar` contain in the end?

Answer (score 1):

To replace 13 with 14 (or any number with the next number), using GNU awk (which I see you're already using since you have `\s` in your script) for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(^\s*"version":.*\.)([0-9]+)(.*)/,a) {$0 = a[1] a[2]+1 a[3]} 1' file
// ...
"version": "1.2.14",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
// ...
```

You COULD just print the original value if you like:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(^\s*"version":.*\.)([0-9]+)(.*)/,a) {print a[2]}' file
13
```

but I suspect you're trying to do that because you're thinking about your real problem the wrong way and trying to solve it with a shell script instead of an awk script.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use `jq` rather than `awk` to parse JSON file.

Assuming you file is:

```
$ cat file
{ "version": "1.2.13",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
   }
}
```

The following command replaces the `version` value by incrementing the last number of the version string. That'll work with a 3 or more number in the string.

```
<file jq '.version=([(.version | split(".")[0:-1][]),(.version | split(".")[-1]|tonumber +1|tostring)]|join("."))'
{
  "version": "1.4.5.14",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm just starting to learn `jq` - can it be done in one call to `jq` or does it need 2 passes? Would that continue to work if the version number was sometimes 4 integers instead of 3?

Comment: I'm also starting to learn `jq`... This is best I came up with. No doubt it can be better and unfortunately I don't yet know how to answer your question. Come back in a few months ;-)

Comment: So far all I've figured out is how use it to convert JSON to TSV for post-processing with awk - beyond that it's syntax seems to be a tad on the cryptic side but I'm hoping that maybe I just have a hump to get over!

Comment: @EdMorton It took a while but I found out how to perform the version replacement in one jq filter. I agree you have to sweat a bit before having efficient jq filter ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Roll on the day when we have a `jq` parser for awk :-)!